# Debugging Jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee

I'm debugging my application and I see that I have an exception in jar file which is built from completely separate Java project. I checked out this project from SVN.

How can I attach this project in Eclipse to my current project and debug this code as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to create a dependency of one project on the other.

> Right Click on your project name > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects

Just make sure that both projects are in the same workspace.