# debugging code in a jar file that is called from inside another project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jar

I debug by java project A as Remote Java Application. I have another java project B whose code I extract as a jar file. I call this jar file from inside my project A. Now I want to debug the code inside my project B when the jar of project B is executed from project A. How can I setup my eclispe debug to do this? (Project B contains a main method)

Comment: Package the jar with source files. If you are using maven, in dependencies you can use download sources.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I packaged the jar with source files. How can I link that up in my debug configuration?

Comment: Try this so link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377767/debugging-jar-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Open the Properties dialog for the project. There is a "Build Path" entry. In this page, you'll see a tab "Libraries" which has a list of all the JARs which are on the classpath.

Click the little arrow to see the subelements of the JAR in question and click on "Source Attachment". This enables the "Edit" button where you can specify where Eclipse should go looking for the sources.